# java DOMXpath get attribute value

Tags: java, xpath, domxpath

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GSP VER="3.2">
   <TM>0</TM>
   <Q>monkey pay</Q>
   <Context>
      <total_results>3</total_results>
   </Context>
   <RES EN="3" SN="1">
      <M>3</M>
      <R N="1">
         <U>link1</U>
         <T>title1</T>
         <S>snippet1</S>
      </R>
      <R N="2">
         <U>link2</U>
         <T>title2</T>
         <S>snippet2</S>
         <PageMap>
            <DataObject type="metatags">
               <Attribute name="viewport" value="width=992, maximum-scale=2.0" />
               <Attribute name="dc.subject" value="atributevalue" />
               <Attribute name="og:title" value="atributevalue" />
               <Attribute name="og:description" value="atributevalue" />
               <Attribute name="og:image" value="atributevalue" />
            </DataObject>
            <DataObject type="cse_image">
               <Attribute name="src" value="atributevalue" />
            </DataObject>
            <DataObject type="cse_thumbnail">
               <Attribute name="width" value="atributevalue" />
               <Attribute name="height" value="atributevalue" />
               <Attribute name="src" value="image2" />
            </DataObject>
         </PageMap>
      </R>
      <R N="3">
         <U>link3</U>
         <T>title3</T>
         <S>snippet3</S>
      </R>
   </RES>
</GSP>
```

and I need to get the value for the attribute name="src" of the tag "Attribute" inside the "DataObject" tag which has the attribute type="cse_thumbnail".

The xpath for this is:
        /GSP/RES/R[@N=2]/PageMap/DataObject[@type='cse_thumbnail']/Attribute[@name='src']/@value

Do you know how can I extract that using DOMXpath in Java?

For now I can get all the R tags with link, title and snippet but I can't extract the PageMap values.

This is how I parse the R tags:

```
    List resultNodes = new DOMXPath("/GSP/RES/R").selectNodes(domDoc);
    Iterator nodeIter = resultNodes.iterator();
    while (nodeIter.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = nodeIter.next();
        Element elem = (Element) object;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why it should not work. 
What about the standard java implementation:

```
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("your path");
```